# wxPython wxBitmapButton with Icon + Label

Tags: python, button

How to get it work?
I tried to create Button with Icon and Label on it. Like these buttons:

[Like this example (image)](http://zetcode.com/img/gui/wxpython/gauge.png)

```
image1 = wx.Image("button_icon.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
self.button1 = wx.BitmapButton(self.panel1, id=-1, bitmap=image1,
        pos=(10, 20), size = (200, image1.GetHeight()+5))
```

It creates some button with icon on it well.
But, how to add a label on it?

I read in docs, that BitmapButton inherits from Button, which has SetLabel() method. I've try

```
self.button1.SetLabel("Continue")
```

but nothing. Button with Icon only.

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `wx.lib.buttons` you get `ThemedGenBitmapTextButton` class for a button containing both an image and text. There are more button classes in that lib.